# tumblr avatar img resize question. Trying to use Regular Expression to resize the img.

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm relatively hopeless with JavaScript writing, and I'm trying to resize the default tumblr avatar image on a notes page. Currently there is no way to include a large avatar in your notes, so I'm trying to use a basic regular expression to replace the dynamically generated URL.

A user's avatar is generated into something like this on all notes:

```
"http://28.media.tumblr.com/avatar_1d3b686efcf0_16.png"
```

...which are 16x16 pixel reductions of a main avatar.  But the system has up to 128px .pngs that can be displayed.  I want to write some JavaScript that looks for every `_16.png` and changes it to `_64.png`.

Here is my crappy script

```
var value = "_16.png";   
var newValue = value.replace( new RegExp( "/_16.png/g"), "_64.png" );  
document.write( newValue );
```

Here's the page to see the results:

http://nutnics.tumblr.com/post/1311264016

Does anybody know if tumblr is overriding this script? or if I'm writing it wrong?

Comment: Where do you want to put that script?

Comment: Top? Should it be somewhere in particular?

Comment: Are you actually doing `document.write`?

Comment: If you have found the answer to this question, please add it as an answer (and only an answer) to this question. There is no need to edit your question to include the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script if put at the end of the document does the trick :

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
    elements[i].src = elements[i].src.replace(/_16\.png/g, '_64.png');
}
```

If you can include jQuery then this is a better option :

```
$(document).ready(function(){      
    $('img.avatar').attr("src", function(){
        return this.src.replace(/_16\.png/g, '_64.png');
    })
});
```

Comment: Nicely done! Yea, I'll use the Jquery one for the time being, but I dont know if tumblr will continue to support jquery (They don't mention anything against it in the theme docs so I might be alright)... If they break it then I'll resort to the previous example.

Comment: See updated post above, Im now trying to see if the javascript can fire multiple times after someone clicks on the "Show more notes" link, effectively loading comments from an xml file...

Answer (score 2):

When you use the RegExp constructor you have to leave the `/` delimiters off, and you have to pass the `g` flag as a separate argument:

```
var re = new RegExp('_16\\.png', 'g');
```

You should also escape the `.` with a backslash because it has a special meaning in a regex.  And, because it's in a string literal, you have to escape the backslash.  But it's much easier to use a regex literal:

```
var newValue = value.replace( /_16\.png/g, '_64.png' );
```

Comment: hmm, it seems this is being overridden by something on tumblr's end, because it is not resizing. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like Allan said you're going to want to use `/_16\.png/g` as your regex, but your code looks like you're writing the regex into the document(?), what you should be doing is something like:

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i += 1) {
    els[i].src = els[i].src.replace(/_16\.png/g, '_64.png');
}
```

Which will change the size of your img elements to 64px!

Also, I'm a big fan of the new stuff in ES5 (the latest version of JavaScript) because it feels a lot more JavaScripty so you could also do this:

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
els.forEach(function (el) {
    el.src = el.src.replace(/_16\.png/g, '_64.png');
});
```

`forEach` is included in most modern browsers but you can add it to those that don't like so:

```
if (!(typeof Array.prototype.forEach === 'function')) {
    Array.prototype.forEach = function (fn) {
        for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i += 1) {
            fn(this[i]);
        }
    };
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: TY for the heads up, that looks like a great solution. For now I'll be using the JQuery option above. High five.